# How to align the text shown in login page of custom credential provider

Tags: windows, credential-providers

Is there any way to align the text (justify/left/right alignment)shown below token field in login page of custom credential provider

[image]

Comment: How did u achieve the above custom widows login? I am trying to implement something similar and have followed a few samples on ICredentialProvider & ICredentialProviderCredential but not having much luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at `credentialprovider.h`

```
typedef /* [v1_enum] */ 
enum _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_FIELD_STATE
    {
        CPFS_HIDDEN = 0,
        CPFS_DISPLAY_IN_SELECTED_TILE   = ( CPFS_HIDDEN + 1 ) ,
        CPFS_DISPLAY_IN_DESELECTED_TILE = ( CPFS_DISPLAY_IN_SELECTED_TILE + 1 ) ,
        CPFS_DISPLAY_IN_BOTH    = ( CPFS_DISPLAY_IN_DESELECTED_TILE + 1 ) 
    }   CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_FIELD_STATE;

typedef /* [v1_enum] */ 
enum _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_FIELD_INTERACTIVE_STATE
    {
        CPFIS_NONE  = 0,
        CPFIS_READONLY  = ( CPFIS_NONE + 1 ) ,
        CPFIS_DISABLED  = ( CPFIS_READONLY + 1 ) ,
        CPFIS_FOCUSED   = ( CPFIS_DISABLED + 1 ) 
    }   CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_FIELD_INTERACTIVE_STATE;
```

There is no provision for alignment for a field in `CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_FIELD_STATE`. There is no API/constant to declare the aligment of a specific field. The only alignment Credential Provider does is "Center alignment".